# How to use Angular CLI correctly if I have a virtual machine and do not want to use localhost

Tags: angular, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a website for which I have a vagrant configured with a virtual machine. Angular CLI works through localhost, can I use "ng serve" without creating a local server, and use an existing one? Ie my server virtual machine.

Comment: you want user to visit your website through the ip of your VM, not "localhost"?

Answer (score 1):

You can run it using `ng serve --host xx.x.x.xx`, using your IP. 
 With that, just access xx.x.x.xx:4200 and it should work fine. Any computer connected to the same network should be able to see it.

Comment: ng serve --host <your virtual box machine IP>